# Numerical integration of a pandas dataframe indexed by datetime using resample.()

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I want to integrate a 5 minute interval into an 1 hour.  Is there a way to do this in pandas itself? Similar to how resample can be used to downscale and average?  I want to downscale and return the integral of each 1 hour period using the 5 minute data.

```
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(300,4), columns=list('ABCD'), index=pd.date_range('2017-01-01 09:00:00', periods=300, freq='5min'))
df=df.resample('1h').mean()  #can as similar method be used to find the numerical integral (eg. with trapezoidal rule)?
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and simply used scipy integrate
e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

data = np.abs(np.random.randn(36000))
ts = pd.Series(data,pd.date_range(start='today', periods=len(data), freq='s'))
ts_int = ts.resample('H').apply(integrate.trapz)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scipy.integrate.simps to apply simpson's Rule for integration. You will have to use a custom resampler and apply the Simpsons integration in the function that is supplied to your custom resampler as an argument.

Here is how you can do it:

```
def custom_function(array_like):
    return  sp.integrate.simps(array_like)   

df = df.resample('1H').apply(custom_function)
```